# Setting up GCP landing zone

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are a small firm in Paris and trying set up a GCP landing zone. completed Cloud Identity. I read we can use terraform-google-modules 0-bootstrap on github to start bootstrap step.

What you need to start bootstrap? create bootstrap project manually, create terraform service account?

does this step is manually run terraform?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the first step manually: create a first project (a bootstrap project) create a billing account and create a service account (with enough permission).

Then you can use your service account credentials to create another projects, link them to the billing account and create resources on them.

Comment: Hi guillaume, thanks for your valuable suggestion. I am using https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-example-foundation which has code. This code building many resources and using many modules and modules inside modules. How to build some resources and not all resources?

Comment: According to the terrraform configuration you should be able to create only the required resources.